# Unable to set data to google line chart, Column not set correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular2-services, google-visualization

> First row is column names. I guess dataTable for the line chart isn't forming correctly.

```
       var arr = [];
       var arrParent = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < __data.length; i++) {
         if (i == 0) {
           arr.push(__data[i].ColumnName1 + ", " + __data[i].Value);
         }
         else {
           arr.push(__data[i].ColumnName1 + ", " + parseInt(__data[i].Value));
          }
       }
         arrParent[0] = (arr);
```

> Populating data for Line Chart

```
        this.lineChartData = {
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        dataTable: **arrParent**,
        options: { title: 'Title' }
      };
```

> Trying to frame the data in the below format. The '__data' above is just a collection of ColumnName1, Value.

```
 this.lineChartData = {
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    dataTable: 
    [
     ['Year', 'Value'],
     ['2004', 1000],
     ['2005', 2000]
    ],
    options: { title: 'Title' }
  };
```

Comment: Tell us what the expected behavior should be. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Question not clear. can you clearly tell what is `__data` and how you expected with `arrParent[ ]`

Comment: @Gamsh Edited the description

Comment: @VivekRanjan please see my answer if it is ok your answer also correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Got it correct, problem was with array formation

```
      var arrParent = [];
      var arrChild = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < __data.length; i++) {
        arrChild.push([__data[i].ColumnName1, (i > 0 ? parseInt(__data[i].Value) : __data[i].Value)]);
      }
      arrParent.push(arrChild);
```

> Data for Line Chart

```
 this.lineChartData =
 {
  chartType: 'LineChart',
  dataTable: arrParent[0]
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

`var arr = [];`
 `var __data=[{'ColumnName1':'Year','Value':'value'},{'ColumnName1':'2004','Value':1000}];`

`for (var i = 0; i < __data.length; i++) {`
 `if (i === 0) {`
   `arr.push([__data[i].ColumnName1 + ", " + __data[i].Value]);`
   `}`
`else {`
`arr.push([__data[i].ColumnName1 + ", " +parseInt(__data[i].Value)]);`
`}`
`}`

here **arr** is in your wanted format. you you can detectly use arr.
`this.lineChartData = {
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        dataTable: arr,
        options: { title: 'Title' }
      };`